# How to I install OpenRefine extensions in OntoRefine

Tags: openrefine, graphdb

Is it possible to use OpenRefine extensions in OntoRefine (part of GraphDB 8.3)? And if yes, how?

What version of OpenRefine is OntoRefine based on?

Comment: I do not see anything in the installation folder of GraphDB which allows to install an extension by simple drag and drop. You should probably ask them the question directly.

Comment: Yes, but GraphDBs documentation seems to prefer that support questions are posted here. Also this would be useful knowledge for any one evaluating the platform. I've also sent them an e-mail and will add the response here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphDB support replied to my e-mail:

- OntoRefine is currently (dec 2017) based on OpenRefine 2.5
- The implementation is packaged in app/lib/workbench/WEB-INF/lib/graphdb-framework-openrefine-{version}.jar

In my case, GraphDB version is 8.3.1 and the installer placed it into C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GraphDB Free\ (on Windows)

So theoretically, it is possible to unpack the graphdb-framework-openrefine-8.3.1.jar file, add a plugin, repackage and replace.

In practice, it's just too much work and it's probably easier to use a standalone OpenRefine and export from there into GraphDB.